# Latex glossary wont show up

Tags: latex, glossary, tex-live

i try to print a glossary, but it wont show up. It doesnt show a error or something. Here is an min. example. I use TeXstudio 2.12.16 and TexLive 2019 on a Win10 machine. It would be very nice if someone could help me.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[]{glossaries}       
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{lvm}{LVM}{Logical Volume Manager}
\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
name=computer,
description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
    stores and manipulates data, and provides
    output in a useful format}
}


\begin{document}


\section{Test}
first : \gls{lvm}
second : \gls{lvm}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I changed the Standardcompiler from pdflatex to latexmk. Same result as before. when i run makeglossaries i get this error message: Prozess gestartet: makeglossaries.exe "main"

"\xxx\xxxx\users\xxx\Documents\Bericht\Latex" CMD.EXE wurde mit dem oben angegebenen Pfad als aktuellem Verzeichnis gestartet. UNC-Pfade werden nicht untersttzt. Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt.

***Call to makeindex failed*** Possible cause of problem: Style file not found. (Have you used \noist by mistake?) Check 'main.alg' for details

C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:902: command failed with exit code 25: perl c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries main

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)

Comment: How do you process the file? You need to call `makeglossaries` at some point.

Comment: The code works fine for me. An easy way to run all necessary commands automatically is to compile with `latexmk filename`

Comment: I use TeXstudio 2.12.16 and TexLive 2019 on a Win10 machine. when i compile it in TeXstdudio it should call latexmk at some Point or not ? i use \makeglossaries directly after \usepackage[]{glossaries}

Comment: I was referring to the **program** `makeglossaries`, that has to be called at some point. `latexmk` would indeed be a good alternative. I cannot say if TeXstudio uses that or not.

Comment: @brettsperrholz texstudio will only use latexmk if you configured it to use it, it is not the default command

Comment: I changed the Standardcompiler from pdflatex to latexmk. Same result as before. when i run makeglossaries i get a error message. thanks for the help so far

Comment: You may need to pass the acronym option to the glossaries package: \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} -- that's what I have in my document. As well as make use of \acrshort and \acrlong (not \gls} while also using \printglossary[type=\acronymtype].